# What would be the best variable usage in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, class, variables

I am encountering few doubts regarding the best approach to use classes and scoped variables in Ruby.
While saving information in a file, using a specific class in order to do it, I would personally store the concerned data in a class variable during the instantiation, instead of instantiating and calling another function directly with the params.

Since I am not really clear, here are the two points I am talking about :

```
# from another class, could be called with the following syntax : 
# className.new('some params').create

def initialize(params)

 @params = params
end

def create

  File.open 'data.csv', 'a+' do |file|
    file.write @params
  end
end

# usage : className.new('some params').create
```

The other possible method would be to only instantiate the class, and passing all the params by calling the create function.

```
def initialize
end

def create(params)

  File.open 'data.csv', 'a+' do |file|
    file.write params
  end
end

# usage :
  class_instance = className.new
  class_instance.create 'some params'
```

From your point of view, which method should be definitively used ? Is there a lack of performance in a case ? What are the risks about using one or another method ?

Comment: The latter is better, plus the `create` method should be a class method (static.)

Comment: Could you please argument why the latter is better ?

Comment: It does not produce a garbage instance variable :) Also, it’s always better to keep parameters as near to their usage as possible.

Comment: Is this true in a case of multi calls ? I mean using the `create(params)`, then a `mail(params)` function, from the same class ? I would have to update two or more information from my script to make it correct, instead of simply updating my initialize() function.

Comment: If multiple calls are all have the same params, there is a design flaw. If params differ from call to call then the former approach just won’t work. And let me repeat it in bold, **make the method static to avoid class instantiation at all**.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, learned something today ;)

Comment: If you are utilizing `@params` throughout the class eg. create, mail, log etc. then your first approach makes perfect sense if you are simply using the the create method to write them to a file and that's it then I would concur with @AlekseiMatiushkin (btw I miss mudasobwa :)

Comment: could inheritance from the `File` class be anyhow useful in this case? Is `classNew#create` just `File#open {|file| block}`? I read the `File.open` method, but I don't understand well C++